# How to re-send intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have intent associated with my application.

Eg. Link to an web page.

Sometimes my application can't handle intent and should redirect it to other application (web browser).

The bottom line is that query parameters in link can't be distinguished from another one.

How can I do that?

Comment: Pleas show some code so we can find out problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with launching Intent chooser.

Comment: Did you simply launch the Intent chooser with the Intent originally sent into your Activity or did you create a new Intent? In a quick sample, when I send the same Intent back to the chooser, the chooser doesn't actually seem to show (causing the loop you described in a [prior comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342882/how-to-re-send-intent#comment18209058_13343465)). I'm wondering if I need to reset something in the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Intent that was sent to your activity by simply calling:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
```

Then you can make any changes to it (if needed) and send it again by calling:

```
startActivity(i);
```

or perhaps:

```
sendBroadcast(i);
```

depending on what you want to trigger.

Comment: But what if I have already my application associated with my intent to be run automatically? It would create loop doesn't it?

Comment: You were talking about re-sending it to the web browser, right? Would it be possible for you to slightly modify the intent to make sure that the web browser gets it, but your app doesn't catch it again? E.g. removing any custom intent filters that you might have added. Or are you simply listening to the same Intents as the web browser, without any modifications?

Comment: I'm simply listening to the url I want pass to the browser.